# Creating a Slider Control with the HTML5 - flash

Tags: flash, html, window, slider

I want something like this
http://developerdrive.com/demo/slider_control/demo.html
but with flash (swf window)...
It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Anything is possible! You could use the built-in slider component found here:

[Use the Slider component](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fa1.html)

First off, you can set the default starting value to the middle like this:

```
var slider:Slider = new Slider();
slider.value = 50;
```

Also set your text field to be 100 by default:

```
someTextField.text = "100%";
```

You can configure a change handler function, and update the image size and text field based on the value it receives.

```
slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, changeHandler);

function changeHandler(e:SliderEvent):void {
    var modifiedPercent:number = 2 * e.value;
    someImage.width *= modifiedPercent / 100;
    someImage.height *= modifiedPercent / 100;
    someTextField.text = modifiedPercent+"%";
}
```

It multiplies the percentage by 2, which essentially makes the slider's range from 0 to 200. It then adjusts image dimensions and text field value ("someImage" being a reference to your image, "someTextField" being a reference to the text).